# How to delete personal token access from git.lab.com in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlab

I am first time using the vs code for setting up the git.lab on my Mac laptop. While setting up personal access code to my site. I have enter Code it for git.lab.com (Default site) ,  can you please guide me where this details gets saved in gitlab and how to delete for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Gitlab go to user preferences (top right corner, preferences), then select `Access Tokens` in the left nav bar.
Or follow this link: https://gitlab.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens

Search your token under 'Active personal access tokens' and `Revoke` it.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier with [GitLab 15.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/05/22/gitlab-15-0-released/#revoke-a-personal-access-token-without-pat-id) (May 2022):

> ### Revoke a personal access token without PAT ID
>
> In previous versions of GitLab, personal access tokens could be deleted only by the ID.
> Because none of the endpoints return an ID from a given value, you couldn’t delete a personal access token if you only had the token value.
>
> You can also now use the `personal_access_tokens/self` endpoint to
> revoke a PAT with a single request.
> The endpoint revokes the PAT used to make the request, making it easy to quickly revoke PATs in case of a leak.
>
> Thank you [Hemanth Krishna](https://gitlab.com/DarthBenro) for your contribution!
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/personal_access_tokens.html#using-a-request-header) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/350240).